# How to create linked multiselect boxes in extjs classic 6

Tags: javascript, web, extjs, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I'm starting my adventure with ExtJS, currently I'm using  version 6.0.2 (Classic). I have to create specific kind of form as shown in link below :

[image: Picture of form]

I think it is a  kind of Html's Select Box  with multiple selection option. 
My question is how can I create it in Ext JS? Is it possible to use ComboBox or other Ext component to create such a form? (I've read Sench docs and I didn't find Selection Box,  whereas MultiSelector has deprecated config MultiSelect).

Thanks in advance for helps.

Comment: Why not the grid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure what you're looking for is called an ItemSelector in ExtJS.

See here: http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.0/classic/Ext.ux.form.ItemSelector.html

The search function for the second box is not available, though. If you absolutely need that, you'll have to override the ItemSelector and/or build your own component for that.

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much :)